# Why j-i-1 value = 2 ? if j = 1, i = -1, -1

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Why in this algorithm the total of j-i-1 is = 1? inside the first loop, I would think is -1,

if j = 1, i = -1 and -1. I'm not clear on this, What's going on?

And also I see j-i = 2? But if j = 1 and i = -1 ?? It should be 0 not 2 right?

```js
var longestPalindrome = function(s) {
    let max=0;
    let start=0;
    if(s.length<2) return s;
    let hasPalindrome = (str,i,j) => {
      while(i >= 0 && j < str.length && str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(j)){
            i--;
            j++;
      }

      console.log('____::j::____', j)
      console.log('____::I::____', i)
      console.log('____::j-i::____', j-i)
      
      console.log('::j-i-1::', j-i-1)
      console.log('::!MAX!::', max)
        if(max<j-i-1){
            start=i+1;
            max=j-i-1;
        }
  
    }
    
    for(let i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        console.log('::::loop:::')
        hasPalindrome(s,i,i);
        hasPalindrome(s,i,i+1);
    }

  return s.substring(start,start+max);
};



console.log('longestPalindrome', longestPalindrome('ac'))
```

Comment: Because of Math? 1 - (-1) - 1 is (1+1) - 1

Comment: `1 - (-1)` is `2`

Comment: one minus negative one is two, minus one gives you one.  (`1 - (-1) - 1 => 1`)  This is basic arithmetic.  I'm confused about what the question is.

Answer (score -2):

if j = 1 and i = -1, the operation j - i would be -> 1 - (-1), which would be the same as doing 1 + 1.
So the result of j -i in this case is 2

Comment: I think you meant to express it as: `+1 - (-1) = +2`...

Comment: @FernandoGiganto What you said is really hard to read.

Comment: Maybe I have explained myself wrong.
What I was trying to say is that: if j = 1 and i = -1, the operation j - i would be -> 1 - (-1), that is, 1 + 1 = 2.
Since - x - is +

Comment: i think you are trying to say that multiplying two negative numbers, or subtracting a negative number produces a positive result? These are just arithmetic identities. I think you need to explain in words, so update your response accordingly.

Comment: I don't know, in my country this way of expressing it is quite common.